# Reliable constant current DC/DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, constant-current

I am looking for a CC converter to charge my lithium battery. Most DC/DC converters with CC/CV are Chinese made with very poor reliability. I need something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9sbuDpeldc) to convert 8-15V to 15V CC at ~5A. Are there any on the market, with up to 100$ price? I could use an LED driver, but they are only up to 1.4A.

Comment: Please link to datasheet rather than a YouTube video. The link's anchor text should explain what the subject of the link is rather than "this".

Answer (score 3):

You should not charge a lithium battery with a CC power supply. They do not reduce current for the end stage, so will over-charge and destroy your battery. That's if you're lucky. If you are unlucky, the battery will destroy your workspace as well as itself.

If you want fast charge for lithiums, then you need a dedicated fast charger solution. As you mention wanting 15 V output, that indicates you have a series pack, so you also need balance charging. This is incorporated into most commercial chargers.

Even people who know what they are doing usually opt for buying a commercial charger for their lithium cells. From the questions you are asking, you do not know enough about charging lithiums to be able to make something yourself safely at present.

Comment: I am charging it with lab bench supply - there is no problem with that. I just want to do that from low voltage DC.

Comment: There IS a problem with lab bench supply ... the charge termination stage of the process requires you to watch the falling current and disconnect at more-or-less the right time. If you're diligently doing that, OK.

Comment: If you're presently charging them with a bench power supply, then doing it with a CC power supply will be a bit worse. You have to watch both to make sure they don't over-voltage the cells. Neither will balance your cells. However you can't do a manual current-based charge termination with the CC charge like you could with a CV power supply charge.